# How to send a tweet using existing accessToken in Twitter+OAuth

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, twitter

I want to post a tweet using Twitter+OAuth. In my application I am loging in the app with twitter and I have twit functionality on some other view controller (other than this login screen), then on that screen I have to login again but I don't want to login again.
Once I am logged in I stored the user details but I don't know how to tweet using these login details or accessToken.

Please help me! thanx!

Comment: Who down voted this question. Use your senses and add comment with the reason for down voting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cached the user accessToken details in NSUserDefaults in the same format as is cached when user logs in 
 Cache connected twitter account details details

```
 {
 "oauth_token" = "";
 "oauth_token_secret" = ;
 "oauth_verifier" = ;
 "screen_name" = ;
 "user_id" = ;
 }
```

and it worked for me :)